# Solving the Riccati equation $y'=ay^2+f(x)y+b$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to know if someone knows a method to solve the following Riccati equation

$$y'=ay^2+f(x)y+b$$

where of course $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$, $f$ is a continuous function and $a,b$ are constants. I know that if $f=C$ with $C$ a constant the equation is a separable equation, but I don't know what happen in the general case.

If someone could give some advice, I will really appreciate it.

Comment: If you follow the [technique described in the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation), substituting $y = -u'/(au)$, the equation becomes linear:  $
u'' + f(x) u' + a b u = 0.
$  Whether or not this helps matters depends on the form of $f(x)$, though.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert $u'' - f(x) u' + a b u = 0$

Comment: @DonP. After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

For a more general case where $a$ and $b$ are not constants but functions of $x$, it is better to first substitute $y=\frac{t(x)}{a(x)}$, where $t(x)$ is a non-zero, differentiable function of $x$ and then $t(x)=\frac{-p'(x)}{p(x)}$, where $p(x)$ is a non-zero, twice differentiable function of $x$.

However, in your special case of a Riccati's equation

$$y' = ay^2+f(x)y+b \tag{i}$$

where $a$ and $b$ are constants, a direct substitution of

$$y=\frac{-p'(x)}{ap(x)} \tag{ii}$$

will reduce $\text{(i)}$ to a second order linear differential equation

\begin{align} 
y' &= \frac{1}{a} (-p' p^{-1})' \\
&= \frac{1}{a} \left(-p' \frac{-1}{p^2} p' + p^{-1}(-p'') \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{a} \left( \left(\frac{p'}{p}\right)^2 - \frac{p''}{p} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{a} \left(a^2y^2-\frac{p''}{p} \right) \\
&= ay^2-\frac{p''}{pa}
\end{align}

where in the second last line we used $\frac{p'}{p}=-ay$. Using $\text{(i)}$, we can then replace $y'$ to get

\begin{align}\require{cancel}
\cancel{ay^2}+f(x)y+b &= \cancel{ay^2}-\frac{p''}{pa} \\
\implies p a f(x) \left(-\frac{p''}{pa} \right) + pab &= -p'' \\
\implies p''-f(x)p'+abp &= 0
\end{align}

You can then solve this second order linear differential equation in the dependent variable $p$. Finally, the solution of $\text{(i)}$ is given by $\text{(ii)}$.

Comment: You might want to use the \align environment, it will make the maths text much neater. See [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Aligning_equations_with_amsmath) under 'Aligning several equations').

Comment: @mattos Thank you very much. I was looking for something like this from a long time. I tried align with & in between but then I found this gather environment much better for the above equations. Is it neater now?

Comment: It's definitely better than before, though it could still be a bit clearer. I think align is probably better. I'll fix it up now and then you can take a look and keep what I changed or edit it back to what you have above.

Comment: @mattos you're welcome. Please edit so that i can see how to do best formatting and use it next time to write my answer.

Comment: @mattos \require{cancel} is needed first, I guess. Though you can remove that cancel slash as it doesn't matter

Comment: It's up to you how you would like it to be formatted with regards to the \cancel etc. I changed some things around as well for readability but you can change them back if you would like. Hopefully the align environment makes sense now. I haven't really used the gather environment because I find the align environment does everything I need but if you are happier with \gather then use that.

Comment: @mattos Thanks. I was not making full use of align environment, but now I got it.